# Vue not updating ARRAY properly using unshift

Tags: laravel, vue.js, duplicates, vuejs2, axios

**PLEASE HELP ME!!!!!**

When my application starts i run an ajax to get all my feeds. These are objects that I then store in my vue variable which is an array.

```
    props:['id'],
    data(){
        return {
            feedData: []
        } 
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/feeds/'+this.id).then(response =>{
            this.feedData = response.data.data;
        });
    }
```

After that when the user types and sends a new post i store the new post in the database and then emit an event to capture the new post from the database. The function for this is in my methods.

```
    methods: {
        captureFeed: function (feedId) {
            const vm = this;
            axios.get('/feeds/'+this.id+'/'+feedId).then(response =>{
                vm.feedData.unshift(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            });
        }
    },
```

The weird thing is that when i successfully get the new feed i just created and try to add it to the array of feeds using unshift for some reason the very first post of the array is duplicated and i never get to see the new post until i refresh the page. When i check the console log, i can see that i got the new feed. The funny thing is that when i use

```
vm.feedData.push(response.data);
```

it works just fine, but the post is at the very bottom which is not what i want!

i have images to show:

first post:

[picture of the first post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrEVO.png)

second post:

[picture of the second post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg9fh.png)

Comment: What does the template look like?

Comment: `<template>
    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-5 mt-m pr-sm pl-sm">
        <timeline-headline></timeline-headline>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <feed-constructor :timeline-id = "id" @newFeedSent = "captureFeed"></feed-constructor>
                <feed v-for = "feed in feedData" :feedContent="feed"></feed>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>`

Comment: Try using a `key` in on the `feed` that you are looping over. `:key="feed.id"` where `feed.id` is some unique value for each feed.

Comment: let me try that now. will get back to you in 2mins

Comment: hmm.. i did something like this where i used the feed id. `<feed v-for = "feed in feedData" :id="'feed-'+feed.id" :feedContent="feed"></feed>` not sure how to use the dynamic key or dynamic feed id to fix this, trying to figure it out

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!!! yes i used the exact code you gave me. i put `:key="feed.id"` inside my feed loop where the `feed.id` is the unique id of the feed from the database. Just tested it and it works great!!! Thanks againa @Bert, was struggling with this all day!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post an answer in a bit.

Comment: Please do. Hope this helps everyone else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that when you are looping over a component, you are [*required* to use a key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component).

> In 2.2.0+, when using v-for with a component, a key is now required.

That being the case, your template should look like this:

```
<feed v-for="feed in feedData" :key="feed.id" :feedContent="feed"></feed>
```

where `feed.id` is a unique value in each feed object. This is because of Vue's DOM update strategy. Using a key helps Vue identify which components need to be created/destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the key param in your template? Like this?

```
 :key="<An ID>"
```

For instance:

```
<div  v-for="(item, index) in array" :key="item.id">
  {{index}} - {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Lucas, your right the `:key="<An ID>"` helps solve this issue, had no idea, going to research and learn more on this